# I need to find the values of A, B and r in this exponential decay function. A, B and r are all constants.

Tags: exponential-function

The function is $f(x)=A+Be^{rx}$.
The y-intercept is $(0, 65.59)$.
The x-intercept is $(78, 0)$.
For this function $B$ has to be negative and $r$ has to be positive to match the required curve shape. At this point all i've found is that $\frac{1}{r}\ln A=78$ and $A+B=65.59$.
I'm just trying to find two simultaneous equations that help find the value of one of the constants in order to find the rest. Cheers

Comment: You have two conditions and three unknowns. You will have a curve of acceptable solutions (if any exist).

Answer (score 1):

You typically need as many equations as unknowns to find the  missing parameters.

$65.59=A+B$, so $B=65.59-A$

$0=A+Be^{78r}=A+(65.59-A)e^{78r}$

$r=-\frac{1}{78}\ln(\frac{-A}{65.59-A})$

$f(x)=A+(65.59-A)(\frac{A}{A-65.59})^{-x/78}$

That's the best you can do without more information. Note this new information doesn't have to be specific function values. It could be, a set area under the curve, maximum value of the first derivative. If you have a set of points you want to approximate, you can probably find a least squares appropriate value for A.